# Prove that the integral of $sin(z)/(z^2+4z+5)$ from negative to positive infinity is $-\pi sin(2)/e$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, laurent-series

I think I've made the problem a lot nastier than it supposed to look.  Here's what I have so far.

First notice that $(z^2+4z+5)$ is equivalent to $(z^2+4z+4)+1$ so our singularities are -2-i and -2+i but the only one we examine is the latter.

To find the line integral, we do $2\pi i$Res(f,-2+i) where f(z)=$e^{iz}/(z^2+4z+4)+1$.  Now from here, when you take the Residue it seems like the "+1" term at the end of the denominator makes this problem a bit messy.  Am I on the right track or did I misinterpret something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there - it is not so messy as you fear: You correctly stated that

$z^2 + 4z + 5 = [z - (-2 + i)][z - (-2-i)]$.

Then the residue is
\begin{equation}
\text{Res}_{z = -2 + i}f(z) = \left.\frac{e^{iz}}{z - (-2-i)}\right|_{z = -2 + i} = \frac{e^{-1 -2i}}{2i},
\end{equation}
so $2\pi i \text{Res}_{z = -2 + i}f(z) = \pi e^{-1 - 2i}$.

By taking the imaginary part, we end up with the desired result.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you got to that result.  The answer I got as a result of finding that residue is $e^{-2+i}+8-2i$

Comment: I've edited my answer with a little more detail. Do you agree with the first equality in the residue calculation?

Comment: okay I got it.  Mistake on my end.